# Отключить responsive уровни LG и MD в bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap, opencart

Есть сайт на opencart 2.3 и соответственно bootstrap 3
Нужно отключить lg и md вообще, что бы сайт не растягивался больше максимального значения SM.

Это возможно?

Answer (score 0):

В `style.css` темы (либо в конце `bootstrap.css`) допишите:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   .container {
      width: 992px;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Я к сожалению это сделал каким-то другим способом, более сложным. Если кому-то поможет ответ - напишите, я помечу как верный, сам проверить не могу.

Comment: @segar опишите ответом ваше решение.

Comment: Не смогу - долго морочился и пока морочился - забыл отписать сюда, а теперь уж и не вспомню. В файле стилей где то менял пороги переключения. И я не уверен, что это правильное решение.